# Java. FileReader не может считать файл

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, почему файл не считывается?

Работаю в Eclipse, может надо в настройках сделать что нибудь?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AvgFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0.0;

        //вывести данные в файл
        FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("demo.txt");
        fout.write("2 3.4 5 6 7.4 9.1 10.5 готово");
        fout.close();
        FileReader fin = new FileReader("demo.txt");
        Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);


        //читать и суммировать числовые значения
        while(src.hasNext()) {
            if(src.hasNextDouble()) {
                sum += src.nextDouble();
                count++;
            }
            else {
                String str = src.next();
                if(str.equals("готово")) break;
                else {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка формата файла.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Всё время выводит "Ошибка формата файла".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в различии десятичного разделителя числа у Вас в файле и у `Scanner`.

В Вашем файле, в качестве десятичного разделителя выступает точка, однако `Scanner`, исходя из текущей локали, считает, что десятичным разделителем должна быть запятая.

Проблему можно решить, установив для `Scanner` локаль, в которой в качестве десятичного разделителя выступает точка, например:

```
Scanner src = new Scanner(fin).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Либо записывать числа в файл, разделяя целую часть от дробной запятой.

Comment: Так там жеж точка

Comment: Спасибо большое) Заработало)) Как можно быть таким слепым :)

Comment: @abbath0767, `Там` – где? В файле точка, да.

Comment: @post_zeew я правильно понимаю что у автора возникла проблема при чтении/записи FileReader/Writer'a, так как при дефолтных настройках локали точки писались/читались как зяпятые?

Comment: @abbath0767, Не совсем. Почитайте ответ.